# Could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have C# application (.NET Core 6) and I have written the following LINQ expression.

```
 var data = query.OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedOn).GroupBy(b => new { b.PackageID, b.PatientId }).ToList();
```

I get following error

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<LAB_ValueBasedResult>()
.Where(item => item.GroupId == 58)
.Where(item => item.HospitalId == 59)
.Where(x => x.IsActive)
.Where(x => x.CreatedOn >= __AddDays_0)
.Where(x => x.CreatedOn <= __AddDays_1)
.Where(x => __lstPatientID_2.Contains(x.PatientId))
.OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedOn)
.GroupBy(b => new {
    PackageID = b.PackageID,
    PatientId = b.PatientId
 })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

I want to Add OrderByDescending and GroupBy in LINQ execute. how could I do it?
Please advise how can I resolve this.

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot enumerate through a DataSet, only a table inside the set.  So you need to select a table..  Does LAB_ValueBasedResult have properties that are enumerable objects like a LIST<>?

Comment: @jdweng No LIST<> in there but if i use like this its working fine                                
 var data = query.OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedOn).ToList().GroupBy(b => new { b.PackageID, b.PatientId });

Comment: What part is the actual issue? If you remove the `OrderByDescending` will the query execute? If you remove the `GroupBy` will the query execute? If the answers are both "no", will the query execute if you remove both?

Comment: @jdweng, given the mention of `DbSet`, this is definitely Entity Framework, so LINQ to Entities must be able to convert the LINQ code to SQL. Even perfectly valid LINQ code cannot always be accepted by all providers.

Comment: Try query.AsEnumerable().  A datatable is not automatically enumerable by rows.  So you have to use dt.AsEnumerable()

Comment: @jdweng using .AsEnumerable() will pull the whole dataset into memory, Grouping should be done on the DB side (before you pull it into memory) I believe the problem is in "__lstPatientID_2.contains", i have encountered translate issues before with .Contains, just wanted to share that

Comment: @THEoneANDonly : With datatable of been using AsEnumerable() for years and not having any issues.  What do you do when the database is not connected to a database?